# How to hide a form's frame at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form. At runtime, how can I hide the form's frame? (The borders with the form name.)

Answer (score 7):

Set the form's [`FormBorderStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx) property to `None`.